# Is there a way to make vertices use external objects?

Tags: vertices

I apologize if my question seems convoluted, I figure if i knew how to describe it simply I'd be able to look it up. Anyway, please bear with me:

What I want is to add objects to vertices, which the vertices coords being the point for their individual origins. For instance, I create a grid out of a subdivided plane, I want to create (for example) UV spheres "on top" of the intersecting vertices. Is there something (similar to setting a bevel object) that allows me to do this? or some other way i could make a "grid" of objects?

Comment: Possibly helpful. https://www.blender.org/manual/de/editors/3dview/object/properties/duplication/dupliverts.html?highlight=dupliverts

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you.